# Why error "Error: Could not find or load main class" occurs with docker RUN?

Tags: java, linux, docker, jar, dockerfile

I have web app and desktop app.  The web app has been added to docker images and everything works. However, the desktop application cannot find the boot class after booting the image. When I run the same command in the command line and docker, everything works in the command line, the application starts correctly, and when I launch the docker image:

```
docker run d36
```

the following error appears:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class mlogger.Main
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
COPY out/artifacts/mlogger_app_jar2/mlogger-app.jar .
CMD java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar mlogger-app.jar
```

I tried to use Add insted of COPY.  I have read all the entries on similar topics and nothing has helped. Maybe I missed something while creating the dockerfile?

Comment: Can you show us the complete stacktrace thanks, including any nested stacktraces.

Comment: @Stephen Ok, how can I do it?

Comment: The method you're using worked fine for me -- I just tried. The Java JVM can clearly find your JAR file, because it's able to read the manifest and try to load mlogger.Main. The fact that it can't do that kind of points to your JAR file being incorrectly structured. Does it have a directory called mlogger, and in that directory a class called Main.class?

Comment: @PawełPamuła - You need to capture whatever is written to standard output and standard error.

Comment: @KevinBoone yes, I have mlogger package in my .jar file and Main.class inside package. I think if my .jar had a bad structure it wouldn't start correctly using the command line. Maybe the fact that the docker doesn't have a desktop environment and I want to run javafx app in it has an impact?

Comment: It's certainly fiddly to run a GUI application in a Docker container, but not impossible. I guess what I'd do in your position is to start with a simpler Java program, with no graphical elements, and check that works in Docker. That would at least prove your build process is sane. Then I'd build the program up gradually, until I found exactly what stopped it working. It's odd though -- the "Can't find or load main class" message is usually pretty clear.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I built and launched the front in React and the web app in Srping Boot via Docker and everything works, instead of running the desktop application via docker, I created a .deb installer.